# Bootstrap CSS Mobile Resize Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into an issue using Bootstrap when re-sizing the page to a mobile size. The input form is shifting to inline and the glyphicon I am using is not staying in the same position once the window is resized. I have included 2 pictures below on how it looks before and after resizing the window.

HTML code for input section:

```
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="end">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="start">
                    <span class="top">Date and Time</span>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class = "input-group-addon"><span id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></div>
                        <input type="text" class="col-xs-4" id="date">
                        <input type="text" class="col-xs-4" id="time">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="submit" onclick="getData()">Search</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="start">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS for the date and time ID's:

```
#date {
max-width: 100px;
min-width: 100px;
font-size: 12px;
}

#time {
max-width: 100px;
min-width: 100px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

[Normal sized look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOlrq.png)

[Mobile sized look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAc5D.png)

Comment: you html is not correct

Comment: What is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you sizing your `#date` and `#time` both to `min-width: 100px` and `max-width: 100px` as well, your div's wont be bigger or smaller then 100px.
Maybe you should use three declarations like:
`width: 150px`, `min-width: 100px` and `max-width: 200px;`

Another way would be the percentage sizing or `@media screen and (...)`

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) has a really good docu to figured it out an learn how to handle with all the diffrent ways of sizing.

Comment: Oh this is interesting, I havent seen this before thanks for sharing

Comment: There are so many sites to learn that much! See: [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/), [codepen](https://codepen.io/) and to try your own stuff and to it [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most beautiful solution, but you can try to force the "input" to be wide as it can be with `class="col-lg-12"`.

Like this:

```
       <div class="col-sm-4" id="end">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="start">
                <span class="top">Date and Time</span>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class = "input-group-addon"><span id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" ></span></div>
                    <input type="text" class="col-lg-12" id="date">
                    <input type="text" class="col-lg-12" id="time">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="submit" onclick="getData()">Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="start">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to keep the inputs centered when I change the width, but it doesn't keep the glyphicon near the inputs still.